# Intentos infructuosos de enviar datos a un servidor externo al recibir una alarma (solo en algunos terminales)

Tags: android

Buenos días, agradecería cualquier idea que pueda dar luz al siguiente asunto: hice una aplicación (no publicada) en la que el usuario programa una o varias alarmas que al recibirse realizan una consulta a un servidor externo.

El proceso funciona bien en la mayoría de terminales, sin embargo hay algunos en el que no. En estos solo funciona si la aplicación está abierta o recientemente desfocalizada.

Al principio pensé que se trataba de la personalición del fabricante, así que configuré la app como protegida en la memoria, permití que iniciara con el sistema y todos los permisos que se le pueden dar. Nada de esto ha servido.

En un principio usé un BroadcastReceiver para recibir las alarmas. Tras hacer unas breves comprobaciones lanzaba un proceso asíncrono (AsyncTask) que hacía la conexión de forma clásica:

```
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try {
        URL url = new URL(Constantes.APIURL + codeApp);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();  // <-- Aquí se produce una excepción
        // e: "java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to servidor.com/123.456.789.111 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (connection refused)"
        ....
}
```

Por lo visto el teléfono entra en modo sleep y no deja que la aplicación use la red. Pasa con Wifi y datos móviles (esto es solo una suposición, lo que sí está claro es que la app normalmente se cierra y se inicia con el recibidor que provoca el AlarmManager).

Más tarde usé la librería Volley para hacer la conexión. Quité el AsyncTask porque la propia librería se encarga de ese trabajo y el resultado ha sido el mismo: si la app está abierta o recientemente cerrada todo funciona bien, pero si el terminal está sin usar se produce el mismo fallo (las alarmas siempre se reciben, la llamada al webservice no).

Entonces decidí extender el recibidor de WakefulBroadcastReceiver:

```
public class RecibidorAlarma extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {  // De la doc oficial: WakefulBroadcastReceiver -> creating and managing a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK for your app
    Log.d("ALARMA ", "Alarma recibida");
    int idAlarmaBD = Integer.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra("id"));
    Intent servicio = new Intent(context, ComprobarHijoService.class);
    servicio.putExtra("idalarma", idAlarmaBD);
    startWakefulService(context, servicio);
}

public class ComprobarHijoService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent){
        .....
        /* Procesos y conexión con Volley */
    RecibidorAlarma.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

De esta forma se producían los mismos resultados. Pensé que como Volley crea un nuevo hilo este no estaría protegido por el Wakelock y el sistema podría cerrarlo. Así que forcé a Volley a ejecutarse en el mismo hilo; según leí por ahí una forma de conseguirlo es así:

```
String url = Constantes.APIURL + codeApp;
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(contexto);
RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future, future);
request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    6000,  // 6 seg de espera al servidor externo antes de fallar
    6,  // 6 intentos de conexión --    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));  // 1f
requestQueue.add(request);

try {
    String respuesta = future.get(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Esperamos 40 seg antes de enviar excepción
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    ......
}
```

Ahora el log indica lo siguiente:

```
03-24 09:46:31.376 9142-9142/com.myapps.aplicacion D/ALARMA: Alarma recibida
03-24 09:46:31.406 9142-30833/ocom.myapps.aplicacion D/ALARMA: Alarma 1 recibida. Se comprobará si debe ejecutarse el código...
03-24 09:46:59.776 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion D/ALARMA: Error en alarma 1: 
03-24 09:47:00.786 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to servidor.com/123.456.789.123 (port 80) after 6000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-24 09:47:00.786 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.doGet(RequestFuture.java:117)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture.get(RequestFuture.java:97)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.myapps.aplicacion.herramientas.ComprobarHijoService.onHandleIntent(ComprobarHijoService.java:93)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java)
03-24 09:47:00.796 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err: Caused by: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to servidor.com/123.456.789.123 (port 80) after 6000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-24 09:47:00.806 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:158)
03-24 09:47:00.806 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
03-24 09:47:00.806 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to servidor.com/123.456.789.123 (port 80) after 6000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
03-24 09:47:00.816 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:152)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:101)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
03-24 09:47:00.826 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.performRequest(HurlStack.java:110)
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:97)
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:   ... 1 more
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
03-24 09:47:00.836 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
03-24 09:47:00.846 9142-30833/com.myapps.aplicacion W/System.err:   ... 16 more
```

Bueno la cosa ahora está así.. ¿Veis algún error de concepto?, ¿es esta la mejor forma de resolver el problema?, ¿cómo hacéis llamadas a servidores externos desde un recibidor broadcast?

Gracias por haberlo leído!

PD. No he podido poner etiquetas más adecuadas al post por falta de Reputación :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado. Los dos terminales que daban problemas usaban MIUI como personalización Android, pues resulta que en Ajustes - Otros - Batería puedes usar perfiles específicos para cada app. Pues bien, ha sido cuestión de darle permisos para conectarse a la red en segundo plano y problema resuelto.
[image: Teléfono con Miui 7]

Gracias a los que habéis dedicado un rato a mirar el asunto.

Comment: También se pueden dar permisos de datos en background en la aplicación propia de Miui Seguridad - Datos usados - estadísticas de datos - Mi app

Comment: Interesante Victor, gracias por la aportación!

Answer (score 0):

El problema no radica en las llamadas, tal vez no lo has notado pero la conexión es denegada, por que simplemente el url no tiene confianza, "trusted connection", (no se como se dice en español), debes revisar que tus url puedan ser visibles.

De hecho noto un intento de conexión con `Volley` y también tienes el mismo error con el timeout de 6 segundos que tienes definido:

```
Caused by: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to servidor.com/123.456.789.123 (port 80) after 6000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

¿En verdad esta es la url del servidor que deseas acceder?:

```
servidor.com/123.456.789.123
```

Esto puede ser la causa de tu problema.

- Como nota importante, si estas usando un emulador recuerda que el host debe ser
  `10.0.2.2` y NO `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Hola Elena, muchas gracias por dedicarle un rato a este asunto. La dirección web y la IP son falsas; las verdaderas pertenecen a un servidor en Internet. En cuanto a la confianza, no debe haber problema porque es una simple dirección http a una web php que devuelve una cadena de texto (json). Todo funciona bien cuando la app está abierta, el problema es cuando se cierra y la abre el Recibidor, en este caso se ejecuta todo menos la llamada http. Funciona bien en la mayoría de teléfonos, solo me he encontrado con 2 en los que se produce este error. Miraré de todas formas esa posibilidad.Gracias!